# why navigator.contacts.create() coming as Cannot call method 'create' of undefined?

Tags: cordova

I am going to save contact number in device using phone gap build. **I have written below logic. build the apk file from phone gap build website. when invoke below function getting error in line navigator.contacts.create();  contacts.create undefined**. Is any thing i missed in code or what?. Anybody help me. great appreciate. Thank you.

```
// create a new contact object
        var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
        contact.displayName = conatctName;

// save First and Last name
var name = new ContactName();
name.givenName = fName;
name.middleName = mName;
name.familyName = lName;
contact.name = name;

// save cell-phone and office-phone
var phoneNumbers = [];
phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('work', workNum, false);            
phoneNumbers[1] = new ContactField('mobile', mobileNum, true);

contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
contact.save();
alert("Contact Saved");
```

Comment: have you wrapped the code in device ready ???

Comment: ya, after device ready only. i am calling. This function feature is after navigation tow screens. but is is not working.

Comment: which version of cordova and have u added the permission in androidmanifest file ?

Comment: I don't have any androidmanifest file. i have done code in HTML5 using NetBeans developer IDE. I have zip entire project and uploaded in to build phone gap website. Within project i have config.xml file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.xml file (or post it).

```
<plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager" />
```

Comment: I have added these feature and plugin. but not working same error. <feature name="Contacts">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Contacts">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager" />
        </feature>
        
        <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager" />